# The quantifiers in the definition of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, quantifiers, almost-everywhere

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ be a sequence of random variables, defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F} , \mathbb{P})$. We say that this sequence converges almost surely to random variable $X$ if, $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \lim_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \}] = 1,$$ which is equivalent to $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1. \tag{1}$$ Sometimes the first quantifier is written at the beginning of sentence, i.e., $$\forall \epsilon\gt 0 ,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1. \tag{2}$$ Are these definitions equivalent? In general, can we take the quantifiers out of $\mathbb{P}[.]$? I'm asking this question because in logic quantifiers should come before the remainder of the formula. The most formal definition which I've found (for the almost sure convergence) is as follows. For some $\mathcal{N}\in \mathcal{F}$ with $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{N}] =0,$ $$\forall{\epsilon \gt 0} \ \forall \omega \not \in \mathcal{N} \ \exists N_{\epsilon, \omega} \ \forall n\ge N_{\epsilon, \omega} \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon. \tag{3}$$ In this definition $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{N}] =0$ is before the quantifiers (except $\exists \mathcal{N} \in \mathcal{F}$ which occurs before $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{N}] =0$), so I don't know how to fix it.

**Edit:** Actually, we can write two other definitions: $$\forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} ,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega:\forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1 \\ \forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \  \forall n\ge N,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1$$When I translate these definitions to the words, it seems that they are all equivalent but I'm not sure. Also it would be interesting if we change the value of probability and ask whether the equivalence continues to hold. For example consider following propositions: $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 0.45 \\ \forall \epsilon\gt 0 ,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 0.45$$

Comment: @Will Would you be more specific, please? Do you mean $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1$$ and $$\forall \epsilon\gt 0 ,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = 1$$ are not equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent. Take $\epsilon =\frac 1 k$ in he second and use the fact that intersection of  a sequence of sets of  probability $1$ has probability $1$.

Comment: You are right they are equivalent

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks. What about the general question? I mean under what conditions can the quantifiers be taken out of $\mathbb{P}[.]$?

Comment: @geetha290krm Also I'm not sure that I understand your solution properly. Could you expand it to an answer, please? In fact there are three definitions here and I think they are equivalent but I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: $(1) \iff (2)$. If you want an answer about this, it's very simple and it will be posted. However, you are now asking about the equivalence of four statements in an edit. This brings the question a bit out of focus in my opinion.

Comment: @Snoop My main question was general, i.e., under what conditions can the quantifiers be taken out of $\mathbb{P}[.]$? So I added the other statements which came to my mind, but maybe no general can be stated. Anyway, if you provide a (dis)proof for any of the equivalences I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proves $(1) \iff (2)$ and it follows the suggestions in the comments. To see this, note that we have
$$\{X_n\to X\}=\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n\geq N}\{|X_n-X|<1/k\}$$
From which it follows that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\{X_n\to X\}\subseteq \bigcup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n\geq N}\{|X_n-X|<1/k\}=:A_k$$
And therefore $P(X_n\to X)=1$ implies $P(A_k)=1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Now suppose $P(A_k)=1$ for all $k$. Define
$$B_k:=A_1\cap (...)\cap A_k=\bigcap_{\ell \leq k}\bigcup_{N\in \mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n\geq N}\{|X_n-X|<1/\ell\}$$
Then $P(B_k)=1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ because
$$P(B_k^c)=P(A_1^c\cup (...)\cup A_k^c)\leq \sum_{\ell \leq k}P(A_\ell^c)=0$$
We also have that $B_k\supseteq B_{k+1}$ and $\cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}}B_k=\{X_n\to X\}$. But then by measure continuity
$$P(X_n\to X)=\lim_{k\to \infty}P(B_k)=1$$

Comment: Thanks. I think the value of probability is critical in this argument. I mean if we replace $P(X_n\to X) = 1$ with any other positive number, say $P(X_n\to X) = 0.35$ the equivalence does not hold. Is this correct? I tried to construct some counterexample but it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome @S.H.W. I'll think about your further question too.

Comment: I've asked it as a separate [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4855259/changing-the-definition-of-almost-sure-convergence).