# Changing the definition of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, quantifiers

Following my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852181/325808), let $0 \lt c \lt 1$  and consider the statements $$\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \forall \epsilon\gt 0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = c, \tag{1}$$ $$\forall \epsilon\gt 0 ,\ \ \ \ \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\in \Omega: \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}] = c. \tag{2}$$ I think in general the equivalence $(1) \iff (2)$ doesn't hold since the proof for the case $c = 1$ heavily relies on the value of probability and the proof doesn't seem to work for any other value except $c = 1$ (and maybe $c = 0$) but I couldn't construct a counterexample. Is my guess correct? If the answer is yes, then what counterexample can be given?

**Edit:** Andrew's answer shows that $(2) \implies (1)$ is true. Let $A_\epsilon = \{\omega\in \Omega: \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ \forall n\ge N \ |X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \lt \epsilon \}$ and $A = \cap_{\epsilon >0} A_{\epsilon}$. We want to show that $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \ P(A_\epsilon) = c \implies P(A) = c$$ holds. Define the conditional probability $\tilde{P}(\cdot) = P(\cdot \cap A_1)/P(A_1)$. Note that $\tilde{P}(\cdot)$ is well-defined since we have $P(A_1) \gt 0$: $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \ P(A_\epsilon) = c \implies P(A_1) = c \gt 0$$ Note that $(A_\epsilon)_{\epsilon \gt 0}$ is a nondecreasing family of subsets which means that $A_{\epsilon_1} \subseteq A_{\epsilon_2}$ for every $\epsilon_1 \le \epsilon_2$. So for $\epsilon \ge 1$ we have $A_1 \cap A_\epsilon = A_1$ and for $\epsilon \lt 1$ we have $A_1 \cap A_\epsilon = A_\epsilon$. This shows that $$\tilde{P}(A_{\epsilon}) = \begin{cases}
P(A_1)/P(A_1) = 1,  & \epsilon \ge 1 \\
P(A_\epsilon)/P(A_1) = c/c = 1, & \epsilon \lt 1
\end{cases}$$ By the [previous result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852181/325808), this shows that $\tilde{P}(A) = 1$ and so $P(A) = P(A \cap A_1) = P(A_1) = c$.
What about the other direction? Does it hold that $(1) \implies (2)$?

Comment: The case $c\in(0,1)$ should not be special since you can always do conditioning / restrict the sample space which reduces back to the case $c=1$

Comment: @Andrew Yes but how should we change the proof so that the case $0 \lt c \lt 1$ is covered?

Comment: The opposite direction doesn't hold. Take $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ with $X_n(\omega_2)=X(\omega)$, and $X_n(\omega_1)=X(\omega_1)+1$. Then $A = \{\omega_2\}$ but $A_2 = \{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$, so any measure with nonzero mass on $\omega_1$ is a counterexample. More direclty, the first equation is about $P(\lim A_\varepsilon),$ while the second equation is about the map $f(\varepsilon) := P(A_\varepsilon)$. Regularity of measure type arguments mean that $f(\varepsilon)$ should go to $P(A)$ as $\varepsilon$ decays, but this behaviour near $0$ can't tell you much about the whole of $f$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks. Could you turn your comment into an answer, please? Also I didn't understand the last sentence "Regularity of measure type arguments...".

Answer (score 2):

We use the notation in the comments.
Define the probability measure $\tilde{\mathbb P}(\cdot) = \mathbb P(\cdot \cap A_1)/\mathbb P(A_1)$. Note $\tilde{\mathbb P}(A_\epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$. If $\epsilon\geq 1$, then $A_\epsilon\cap A_1 = A_1$. If $\epsilon \leq 1$, then per our hypothesis $$\tilde{\mathbb P}(A_\epsilon) = \mathbb P(A_\epsilon \cap A_1)/\mathbb P(A_1) = \mathbb P(A_\epsilon)/\mathbb P(A_1) = c/c=1$$
Continuity of measure therefore implies $X_n \to X$ $\tilde{\mathbb P}$ -almost surely. We conclude $\mathbb P(\lim X_n = X) = c$.

Comment: What do you mean by a.b.f.o?

Comment: all but finitely often. It is shorthand for the set you wrote in (2) (with $\epsilon = 1$). The shorthands i.o. (infinitely often) and some variation of a.b.f.o. are often used in probability.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why we have $X_n \to X$ $\tilde{\mathbb P}$-almost surely, please?

Comment: In the post you linked, (1) and (2) are equivalent when $c = 1$. Here, by defining $\tilde{\mathbb P}$ we have recovered that case. (To make it more clear, you can forget about $\tilde \Omega$ and $\tilde{\mathcal F}$. The measure $\tilde{\mathbb P}$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, it was poorly written by me... I removed it from the answer)

Comment: Let me be clear. We want to show that $$P(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon) = c \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \ P(A_\epsilon) = c$$ and we define $\tilde{P}(\cdot) = P(\cdot \cap A_1)/P(A_1)$ but how does this help us to prove the equivalence?

Comment: If you agree that the convergence is $\tilde P$ almost sure, then $P(\lim X_n=X)=P(A_1)$

Comment: If we suppose that $P(\{\lim X_n = X\} = \{\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon\}) = c$ holds, then the only thing that we can say is $$\tilde{P}(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon) = P(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon \cap A_1)/P(A_1) = P(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon)/P(A_1) = c/P(A_1).$$

Comment: Yes, and you are assuming $P(A_1)=c$, so not sure where you are objecting to?

Comment: I don't see how $P(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon) = c$ implies $P(A_1) = c$ and hence $\tilde{P}(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon) = 1$. Sorry that I don't get your point.

Comment: see the edit i made

Comment: I see, thanks. What about the other direction? I mean that $P(\cap_{\epsilon \gt 0} A_\epsilon) = c$ holds. Conditioning on $A_1$ doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: Consider a case where $X_n\to X$ with $\mathbb P$ probability $c$ and all the random variables in question are bounded. On the other hand, one might even wonder if it is possible $\mathbb P(A_\epsilon)=c$ for all $0<\epsilon<r$ for some constant $r$. Such an example does not easily come to mind for me, at least